# How do I pass the captured image to other Activity

Tags: android, android-camera

I wanted to create my own camera app.

The MainActivity has an `ImageView` that has camera image when it is clicked, it will go to a CameraActivity. Once I press the "camera" `ImageView`, the pictures will be taken. The taken pictures will return to the MainActivity and show on a gallery widget with `ViewSwitcher`. the problem is, I have no idea how to pass the photo from the CameraActivity back to MainActivity.

Hope anyone could give a hint or example?

Comment: You want to use inbuilt camera or modified camera?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `startActivityForResult()` when you start CameraActivity from MainActivity`. then you can get path of taken picture in`onActivityResult()` in your MainActivity.

**for calling camera activity from MainActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CameraActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

pass the path of current captured image through intent from CameraActivity to MainActivity,
 have look at following code snippet for it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Imagepath", your ImagePath);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
```

and then in `onActivityResult()` you will get that path of image, with that path you can access image in MainActivity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

try{

    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        data.getData();
        imagePath= data.getStringExtra("Imagepath");
        System.out.println("image Path:- " + imagePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below given method to open camera in your **MainActivity**

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

And implement `onActivityResult()` in your **MainActivity** to get the clicked image:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

Add **Permission** in your Manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem you have using the answers above of course,

but what I would do is take the actual files path of the shooted image and save it in some singleton photo manager.

In that scenario you will not transfer unnecessary bytes between activities. You will have all of your images in one place and you can use them whenever you need in the entire app.

I would also use [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for displaying that images so you will increase the memory management and the performance of your app.

Of course you can choose another photo loading library as:
Picasso, [Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/) or something else. This is up to you.

Regards.